# What is the input size of the image to CNN when performing object detection with the model created by Tensorflow Object Detection API?

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection, object-detection-api

I used the Tensorflow Object Detection API (TF1) and created a file of frozen_inference_graph.pb of Faster R-CNN.
After that, I was able to apply object detection to the image using "Object_detection_image.py" in the GitHub repository below.

[EdjeElectronics/TensorFlow-Object-Detection-API-Tutorial-Train-Multiple-Objects-Windows-10](https://github.com/EdjeElectronics/TensorFlow-Object-Detection-API-Tutorial-Train-Multiple-Objects-Windows-10)

When I use this code, how large is the input size of images to Faster R-CNN?
I set both "min_dimension" and "max_dimension" of "image_resizer {" in the config file to 768.
When I perform object detection, is the input size of images to Faster R-CNN automatically resized to this size?
The size of my images I prepared is 1920 x 1080 pixels, and I think it has been resized to 768 x 768 pixels.

If anyone knows about this, please let me know.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're using `Object_detection_image.py` you can modify the code to print out the size of image being used:

```
# ... 
image = cv2.imread(PATH_TO_IMAGE) 

# Add this after line 92:
height, width, channels = image.shape
print height, width, channels 

image_rgb = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
...
```

Comment: I tried what you told me and the terminal displayed [1080, 1920, 3]. Thus, if you use Edje Electronics' Object_detection_image.py, does that mean that a 1920x1080 image will be input to the Faster R-CNN in its original size? According to the principle of CNN, it seems strange ...

Comment: I would say yes based on the code in `Object_detection_image.py`. I did check image resizer - `resizer.py` script that exists in the same repo you shared and that is basically a script that will resize all images to 1/8 of the size in a given folder. You can use that script to shrink images and then feed them to the detector.

Comment: I see, I knew I was inputting a large image of 1920 x1080 pixels into FasterR-CNN. Thank you for your advice!